# Windows Runtime App TypeCode

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-store-apps

I am trying to port the [Basic Dynamic LINQ VB Example](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) by Scott Guthrie to use in my *Windows Store App* on my *Windows 8.1 Pro* machine.

The `TypeCode` enum and its related functions are no longer available (Source: MSDN social Post titled: "Is the standard enum 'TypeCode' omitted from Store and Phone 8 ???" (Can't link, not enough rep)) in *.NET for Windows Store Apps*.

### How should I best translate this TypeCode comparison code?

From the `PromoteExpression()` function in the `ExpressionParser` class:

```
Dim value As Object = Nothing

Select Case Type.GetTypeCode(ce.Type)
    Case TypeCode.Int32, TypeCode.UInt32, TypeCode.Int64, TypeCode.UInt64
        value = ParseNumber(text, target)
    Case TypeCode.Double
        If target.Equals(GetType(Decimal)) Then value = ParseNumber(text, target)
    Case TypeCode.String
        value = ParseEnum(text, target)
End Select

If value IsNot Nothing Then Return Expression.Constant(value, type)

(ParseNumber() and ParseEnum() are functions defined in the class.)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to change the `Select Case` block to a set of `If Else` statements, and the comparisons from `TypeCode` to `GetType`:

```
Dim type = ce.GetType()
If type Is GetType(Int32) OrElse type Is GetType(UInt32) OrElse _
   type Is GetType(Int64) OrElse type Is GetType(UInt64) Then
    value = ParseNumber(Text, target)
ElseIf type Is GetType(Double) Then
    If target.Equals(GetType(Decimal)) Then value = ParseNumber(Text, target)
ElseIf type Is GetType(String) Then
    value = ParseEnum(Text, target)
End If
```

Comment: One small note before I accept: The line is `Select Case Type.GetTypeCode(ce.**Type**)`.  It is my fault the I did not include that `ce` is a [ConstantExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.constantexpression.type(v=vs.110).aspx) in the question.  I don't fully understand how he is comparing `ByteCode`s (like does a `Single` match for a` Double` or if anything tricky is going on) and how to get that same functionality by comparing types.  This is a separate problem though and I believe your solution would work for someone else.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski no worries, I think ConstantExpression.Type resolves to the type of the expression's value which is what I think you want here. Also I think if you want to coerce from a ``single`` you'll have to explicitly check for it.